# What is the grammatical function of 'since' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

What is the grammatical function of 'since' in the following sentence?

> Four years had passed since his father died.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence *since* is used as a [subordinating conjunction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subordinating_conjunction). It links together a main clause and a subordinate clause (an adverbial subordinate clause in this case).

Answer (score 0):

From dictionary.com:

**adverb**
1.from then till now (often preceded by ever  ): He was elected in 1978 and has been president ever since.

2.between a particular past time and the present; subsequently: She at first refused, but has since consented.

3.ago; before now: long since.

**preposition**
4.continuously from or counting from: It has been warm since noon.

5.between a past time or event and the present: There have been many changes since the war.

Answer (score 0):

It's serving as a preposition. They state a relationship in space or time, literally or figuratively, and in this case it is in time and literal.